# How can I write a NeoVim plugin with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, neovim

I heard that one of the advantages of NeoVim is a more flexible plugin architecture.
Is there an API for writing plugins in JS?

There are some projects which seem to be related to this:
[neovim/node-host](https://github.com/neovim/node-host),
[neovim/node-client](https://github.com/neovim/node-client), [fritzy/node-neovim](https://github.com/fritzy/node-neovim), [rhysd/promised-neovim-client](https://github.com/rhysd/promised-neovim-client)
but I'm not sure how to use them.
How do I access [Vim functions](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#functions) or commands, or equivalent functionality (and where is this documented)?

---

promised-neovim-client interacts with a NeoVim process by attaching to its stdin and stdout.
So maybe from within NeoVim, I could start a promised-neovim-client script and pass it the pid of the running NeoVim process and the script could attach to its stdin and stdout?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. [Install](https://github.com/neovim/node-client#installation) the node-client

   - `npm install -g neovim`
   - Run `:checkhealth` to confirm.
2. From the [quickstart](https://github.com/neovim/node-client#examples), paste the sample code (below) into `rplugin/node/index.js` somewhere on your Nvim *runtimepath* (e.g. `~/.config/nvim/rplugin/node/index.js`).
3. Run `:UpdateRemotePlugins`.
4. Restart Nvim.
5. Try the `:SetMyLine` command (which was defined in the above code sample).

#### Sample code

```
function onBufWrite() {
  console.log('Buffer written!');
}

module.exports = (plugin) => {
  function setLine() {
    plugin.nvim.setLine('A line, for your troubles');
  }
  plugin.registerCommand('SetMyLine', [plugin.nvim.buffer, setLine]);
  plugin.registerAutocmd('BufWritePre', onBufWrite, { pattern: '*' });
};
```

Comment: Is the NeoVim API in `node-host` the same as this: https://github.com/neovim/node-client/blob/master/index.d.ts ?

Comment: When I run `:UpdateRemotePlugin` I get `function remote#host#UpdateRemotePlugins[6]..<SNR>47_RegistrationCommands[15]..remote#h
ost#Require[13]..provider#pythonx#Require, line 14                                     
Vim(let):E902: "" is not an executable                                                 
function remote#host#UpdateRemotePlugins[6]..<SNR>47_RegistrationCommands[15]..remote#h
ost#Require[13]..provider#pythonx#Require, line 21                                     
Vim(for):E121: Undefined variable: channel_id`

Comment: I got the same error after running :UpdateREmotePlugin - It turned out that you apparently also need to have a nvim package for python installed. I solved it by running `python3 -m pip install --user --upgrade pynvim` in a terminal.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely write neovim plugins in javascript. From https://github.com/neovim/neovim/blob/master/runtime/doc/remote_plugin.txt#L7

> Extensibility is a primary goal of Nvim. Any programming language may be used
>   to extend Nvim without changes to Nvim itself. This is achieved with remote
>   plugins, coprocesses that have a direct communication channel (via |RPC|) with
>   the Nvim process.
>
> Even though these plugins run in separate processes they can call, be called,
>   and receive events just as if the plugin's code were executed in the main
>   process.

You just gotta talk to remote api

> A Neovim remote plugin (rplugin) is any program that talks to nvim through the remote API (which can be reached via any arbitrary transport mechanism: TCP address, named pipe, stdin/stdout, ...).

I also couldn't find the remote API documentation. There was some examples in `neovim/node-client`.

Could you also take a look in to this [file](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/blob/1f8a3da796dd3418c5204c76192179dbdd6a5373/runtime/doc/msgpack_rpc.txt)

Comment: On master, remote API is now documented at `:help api-funcs`.

Comment: In later versions of Nvim, help tag was changed to simply `:help api`.